# Tree Java Insert

Tags: java, tree

I'm having a problem with a Tree question. No errors in the code; it's just a wrong output. The problem is when I insert "100", it gives a wrong number of leaves and height and also inorder Traversal is wrong. Here is the binary tree class:

```
public class BinaryTree {

    //Definition of the node
    protected class BinaryTreeNode {

        Object info;
        BinaryTreeNode llink;
        BinaryTreeNode rlink;
    }
    protected BinaryTreeNode root;

    //default constructor 
    //Postcondition: root = null;
    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    //copy constructor
    public BinaryTree(BinaryTree otherTree) {
        if (otherTree.root == null) //otherTree is empty
        {
            root = null;
        } else {
            root = copy(otherTree.root);
        }
    }

    //Method to determine whether the binary tree is empty.
    //Postcondition: Returns true if the binary tree is empty;
    //               otherwise, returns false.    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (root == null);
    }

    //Method to do an inorder traversal of the binary tree.
    //Postcondition: The nodes of the binary tree are output
    //               in the inorder sequence.
    public void inorderTraversal() {
        inorder(root);
    }

    //Method to do a preorder traversal of the binary tree.
    //Postcondition: The nodes of the binary tree are output
    //               in the preorder sequence.
    public void preorderTraversal() {
        preorder(root);
    }

    //Method to do a postorder traversal of the binary tree.
    //Postcondition: The nodes of the binary tree are output
    //               in the postorder sequence.       
    public void postorderTraversal() {
        postorder(root);
    }

    //Method to determine the height of the binary tree.
    //Postcondition: The height of the binary tree is returned.    
    public int treeHeight() {
        return height(root);
    }

    //Method to determine the number of nodes in the 
    //binary tree.
    //Postcondition: The number of nodes in the binary tree
    //               is returned.       
    public int treeNodeCount() {
        return nodeCount(root);
    }
    //Method to determine the number of nodes in the binary 
    //tree to which p points. 
    //Postcondition: The number of nodes in the binary tree
    //               to which p points is returned.    

    private int nodeCount(BinaryTreeNode p) {
        if (p == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (1 + nodeCount(p.llink) + nodeCount(p.rlink));
        }
    }

    //Method to determine the number of leaves in the 
    //binary tree.
    //Postcondition: The number of leaves in the binary tree
    //               is returned.       
    public int treeLeavesCount() {
        return leavesCount(root);
    }
    //Method to determine the number of leaves in the binary 
    //tree to which p points.
    //Postcondition: The number of leaves in the binary tree
    //               to which p points is returned.    

    private int leavesCount(BinaryTreeNode p) {
        if (p == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (p.llink == null && p.rlink == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return (leavesCount(p.rlink) + leavesCount(p.llink));
    }

    //Method to destroy the binary tree.
    //Postcondition: root = null     
    public void destroyTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    //Method to make a copy of the binary tree 
    //specified by otherTree points. 
    //Postcondition: A copy of otherTree is assigned to
    //               this binary tree.   
    public void copyTree(BinaryTree otherTree) {

        if (this != otherTree) //avoid self-copy
        {
            root = null;

            if (otherTree.root != null) //otherTree is nonempty
            {
                root = copy(otherTree.root);
            }
        }

    }

    //Method to make a copy of the binary tree to 
    //which otherTreeRoot points. 
    //Postcondition: A copy of the binary tree to which
    //               otherTreeRoot is created and the reference of
    //               the root node of the copied binary tree
    //               is returned.
    private BinaryTreeNode copy(BinaryTreeNode otherTreeRoot) {
        BinaryTreeNode temp;

        if (otherTreeRoot == null) {
            temp = null;
        } else {
            temp = new BinaryTreeNode();
            temp.info = (((String) otherTreeRoot.info));
            temp.llink = copy(otherTreeRoot.llink);
            temp.rlink = copy(otherTreeRoot.rlink);
        }

        return temp;
    }//end copy

    //Method to do an inorder traversal of the binary
    //tree to which p points.  
    //Postcondition: The nodes of the binary tree to which p
    //               points are output in the inorder sequence.    
    private void inorder(BinaryTreeNode p) {
        if (p != null) {
            inorder(p.llink);
            System.out.print(p.info + " ");
            inorder(p.rlink);
        }
    }

    //Method to do a preorder traversal of the binary
    //tree to which p points.  
    //Postcondition: The nodes of the binary tree to which p
    //               points are output in the preorder sequence.       
    private void preorder(BinaryTreeNode p) {
        if (p != null) {
            System.out.print(p.info + " ");
            preorder(p.llink);
            preorder(p.rlink);
        }
    }

    //Method to do a postorder traversal of the binary
    //tree to which p points.  
    //Postcondition: The nodes of the binary tree to which p
    //               points are output in the postorder sequence.      
    private void postorder(BinaryTreeNode p) {
        if (p != null) {
            postorder(p.llink);
            postorder(p.rlink);
            System.out.print(p.info + " ");
        }
    }

    public void insert(String x) {
        BinaryTreeNode c1, c2, nn;
        nn = new BinaryTreeNode();
        nn.info = x;
        nn.llink = null;
        nn.rlink = null;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            root = nn;
        } else {
            c2 = root;
            c1=null;
            while (c2 != null) {
                c1 = c2;
                if (c2.info.equals(x)) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (((String) c2.info).compareTo(x) > 0) {
                        c2 = c2.llink;
                    } else {
                        c2 = c2.rlink;
                    }
                }
            }
        if (((String) c1.info).compareTo(x) > 0) {
            c1.llink = nn;
        } else {
            c1.rlink = nn;
        }
    }
    }

    public boolean search(String x) {
        boolean found = false;
        BinaryTreeNode c1;
        BinaryTreeNode c2 = root;
        while (c2 != null && !found) {
            c1 = c2;
            if (c2.info.equals(x)) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                if (((String) c2.info).compareTo(x) > 0) {
                    c2 = c2.llink;
                } else {
                    c2 = c2.rlink;
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
    //Method to determine the height of the binary tree
    //to which p points. 
    //Postcondition: The height of the binary tree to which p
    //               points is returned.   

    private int height(BinaryTreeNode p) {
        if (p == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + max(height(p.llink), height(p.rlink));
        }
    }

    //Method to determine the larger of x and y.
    //Postcondition: The larger of x and y is returned.    
    private int max(int x, int y) {
        if (x >= y) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return y;
        }
    }

    public void deleteNode(String deleteItem) {
        BinaryTreeNode current;  //reference variable to 
        //traverse the tree
        BinaryTreeNode trailCurrent; //reference variable 
        //behind current
        boolean found = false;

        if (root == null) {
            System.out.println("Cannot delete from the empty tree.");
        } else {
            current = root;
            trailCurrent = root;

            while (current != null && !found) {
                if (current.info.equals(deleteItem)) {
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    trailCurrent = current;
                    if (((String) current.info).compareTo(deleteItem) > 0) {
                        current = current.llink;
                    } else {
                        current = current.rlink;
                    }
                }
            }//end while
            if (current == null) {
                System.out.println("The delete item is not in "
                        + "the list.");
            } else if (found) {
                if (current == root) {
                    root = deleteFromTree(root);
                } else if (((String) trailCurrent.info).compareTo(deleteItem) > 0) {
                    trailCurrent.llink = deleteFromTree(trailCurrent.llink);
                } else {
                    trailCurrent.rlink = deleteFromTree(trailCurrent.rlink);
                }
            }//end if
        }
    }//end deleteNode        
    //Method to delete the node, to which p points, from the
    //binary search tree.
    //Postcondition: The node to which p points is deleted
    //               from the binary search tree. The reference
    //               of the root node of the binary search tree
    //               after deletion is returned.

    private BinaryTreeNode deleteFromTree(BinaryTreeNode p) {
        BinaryTreeNode current;        //reference variable to 
        //traverse the tree
        BinaryTreeNode trailCurrent;   //reference variable 
        //behind current
        if (p == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: The node to be deleted "
                    + "is null.");
        } else if (p.llink == null && p.rlink == null) {
            p = null;
        } else if (p.llink == null) {
            p = p.rlink;
        } else if (p.rlink == null) {
            p = p.llink;
        } else {
            current = p.llink;
            trailCurrent = null;

            while (current.rlink != null) {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current.rlink;
            }//end while

            p.info = current.info;

            if (trailCurrent == null) //current did not move; 
            //current == p.llink; adjust p
            {
                p.llink = current.llink;
            } else {
                trailCurrent.rlink = current.llink;
            }
        }//end else

        return p;
    }//end deleteFromTree
}
```

and here is the main class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Evil Weevil
 */
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree a=new BinaryTree();
        a.insert("88");
        a.insert("75");
        a.insert("100");
        a.insert("70");
        a.insert("20");
        a.insert("70");      
        a.insert("14");
        System.out.println("InorderTraversal Tree:");
        a.inorderTraversal();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("PreorderTraversal Tree:");
        a.preorderTraversal();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("PostorderTraversal Tree:");           
        a.postorderTraversal();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println(" Tree Node Count:");
        System.out.println(a.treeNodeCount());
        System.out.println(" Tree Leaves Count:");
        System.out.println(a.treeLeavesCount());
        System.out.println(" is the Tree Empty :");
        System.out.println(a.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(" Tree Height(longest chain of nodes ):");
        System.out.println(a.treeHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry meant to move the answer to a comment but I don't seem to be able to fully delete it there.

Answer (score 0):

The expected order is:

"100" "14" "20" ...

if you expect

"14" "20" ....

you probably want to use numbers istead of strings. The reason ist that strings are compared char by char, starting from the left. So '0' < '4' means that 100 is sorted before 14. If you need to use strings for some reason, make sure they have the same length. Use "014" "020" etc.

Comment: you're the man my friend thank you very much just needed this explanation :)

Comment: but can you edit the insert method so i can insert integer values directly cuz i tried to add the DataElement class it didn't work because there is compareTo method

Comment: I think replacing "String" with "Integer" in the code would do the job. Or you could just use "Comparable", replacing both, "Object" as the type of "info" and "String" as the parameter type for the methods. This would also allow you to remove the type casts. The cleanst solution would probably be to use generics, i.e.  "class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable>..."

Answer (score 0):

If you watch your data structure in memory using a debugger you see that each node of the tree has one child only (always the left one, except "100" that has the right child), so the output is correct: you have only one leaf node and the longhest chain (it's the only one!) is made of 6 nodes.  Obviously this is not what you were expecting, so the problem is in the insert() method, but this method has no "postcondition" comment so it is not clear what kind of insertion logic you want to obtain.

The answer of Stefan Haustein is appropriate too: testing with strings containing numbers can be misleading.

Comment: can you edit the insert method for me in a way that takes integer parameter ??!!! that's what im looking for ?? i tried making the DataElement Class they're always error in the compare method :(

Comment: Just replace any occurence of the word "String" with "Integer".  However using generics would be the best solution as already suggested by Stefan.